# Shutting down a linux system

Tags: linux, shutdown

I am quite new to Linux and started using KDE Linux as my main os. I was wondering why does my Linux system start up with running programs and processes from the last session when I start it up again? I like to use the terminal a lot and I just like to use the "poweroff" command in the terminal. My friend told me to use the "shutdown 0" command but it didn't help. Is there a better way to shutdown my system so it would start up with any programs or processes running from the recent session?

Comment: I'm not a KDE user, but in other desktop environments like Xfce there is a settings configuration for startup programs. In Xfce there is a simple checkbox for whether or not to remember the running programs from your previous session. I suspect there is something like this for KDE, and it should take effect regardless of how you terminate your session or shut down your system.

Answer (score 1):

There's a setting in KDE where you it can save a session, so that if you leave some applications open, on next startup, it'll reopen those same application again. You're looking to start with an empty session.

[KDE Settings/System Startup and Shutdown](https://userbase.kde.org/System_Settings/Startup_and_Shutdown#Session_Management)

Comment: This is the correct answer.  The option is `Start with empty session ` https://userbase.kde.org/images.userbase/4/40/Snapshot-kde-session-manager-config.png

Answer (score 0):

`shutdown -P now`

But make sure your bios settings are correct and that it's not hard-wired to go into a sleep/standby mode as it seems to be doing.

Answer (score 0):

When your friend suggested using `shutdown 0`, perhaps the intended command was actually meant to be:

```
sudo init 0
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to use `sudo shutdown -h now` or `sudo shutdown -h 35` if you want to shut it down after 35 minutes

It is also very handy to disable sudo for shutdown command so you can run it as a simple user.